# ParallelScan result order from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Consider the following aspects:

- Java AWS SDK 1.x
- No new register has been put to the table during the tests.
- Regardless the number of the parallel segments managed internally in DynamoDB.

Does the parallelScan search from the AWS DynamoDB SDK always return the result on the same order?

Comment: I don't think you should expect a scan, parallel or not, to return items in any specific order. The one constant is that it will return all items (eventually, pagination assumed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scan order will be the same between calls. All items in the table have an order to them. This is needed for parallel scans and LastEvaluatedKey behaviors to work correctly. You can't anticipate the order but it's necessarily stable between invocations.

Comment: Before you answer, I validated this by running the same parallelScan many times and all of them were the same, in the same order. Good to have a second validation with a great explanation here. Thanks!